# Model doesn't rotate around pivot point after importing scn. into Xcode

Tags: 3d-view, export, 3d-cursor

I export my model from blender via Autodesk into scn. file to use it in Xcode. Once I want to rotate the object on my phone it rotates perfectly horizontal around itself but for some reason not vertical. Vertical it lets the model fly up in huge circles around a point instead of sticking to the point and rotating itself.

Does anyone have an idea what the problem could be? I tried adjusting the camera in Xcode but I will have nearly to 200 different single objects that need to be rotated in 360 so I wonder if this could be solved in blender somehow.

I also made sure , that the pivot point and the 3d cursor are in center of origin.

Thanks alot

Comment: I figured out that after adjusting the camera in Xcode to the hight of the pivot point it does rotate perfectly. Only if I export the object in 90degrees angle (so that it opens the object from the side on the phone) then it flips around and the rotation is completely off even though the camera is positioned the exact same way